# How to convert a fraction to binary?

Tags: algorithm

I don't know how to convert from a fraction to binary. When I search it, there has a solution shows that:

```
    1              1
-- (dec)  =   ---- (bin)
10            1010


       0.000110011...
      -------------
1010 | 1.0000000000
         1010
       ------
         01100
          1010
         -----
          0010000
             1010
            -----
             01100
              1010
             -----
              0010
```

I don't know how and why to do it.

Comment: Do you know how to convert a fraction to decimal?  It's like that, but with 2 instead of 10.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at converting the decimal value of `0.625` to binary.

**Step 1:** Begin with the decimal fraction and multiply by 2. The whole number part of the result is the first binary digit to the right of the point.

```
Because .625 x 2 = 1.25, the first binary digit to the right of the point is a 1.
So far, we have .625 = .1??? . . . (base 2) .
```

**Step 2:** Next we disregard the whole number part of the previous result (the 1 in this case) and multiply by 2 once again. The whole number part of this new result is the second binary digit to the right of the point. We will continue this process until we get a zero as our decimal part or until we recognize an infinite repeating pattern.

```
Because .25 x 2 = 0.50, the second binary digit to the right of the point is a 0.
So far, we have .625 = .10?? . . . (base 2) .
```

**Step 3:** Disregarding the whole number part of the previous result (this result was .50 so there actually is no whole number part to disregard in this case), we multiply by 2 once again. The whole number part of the result is now the next binary digit to the right of the point.

```
Because .50 x 2 = 1.00, the third binary digit to the right of the point is a 1.
So now we have .625 = .101?? . . . (base 2) .
```

**Step 4:** In fact, we do not need a Step 4. We are finished in Step 3, because we had 0 as the fractional part of our result there.

```
Hence the representation of .625 = .101 (base 2) .
```

**Decimal 1/10 converts to an infinite binary fraction.**
In your question you said that `1/10` in decimal equals `1/1010` in binary. `.1 (1/10)` in decimal actually equals 0.0**0011**0011**0011**0011... in binary.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional value to Binary number conversion

1. The fraction value is multiplied by 2 and
        result has a decimal (1 or 0) and  a fraction value.
2. take the faction value for step 1 operation.
3. The repeat process until the fraction value reached to 0.
4. collects a decimal value from bottom to up

   fraction = .125

   ```
         = .125 x 2    
         = 0.250 x 2
         = 0.50  x 2
         = 1.0
   ```

   fraction = 0.125 = 100

   Results
     given fraction value (base 10)= 0.125
     into binary bits (base 2)    = 0.100

   [Real number to binary conversion](http://cljavacode.blogspot.com/2017/03/real-number-to-binary-conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a binary weighted fraction each digit to the right of the decimal point is a power of (1/2) (or the negative of power of 2) smaller than the one to the left.  The first rightward digit has a weight of 1/2, the second is 1/4, the third 1/8, and so on.

So a 0.111 (base-2) is:

```
1*(0.5) + 1*(0.25) + 1*(0.125) = 0.875
```

And a 0.0101 (base-2) is:

```
0*(0.5) + 1*(0.25) + 0*(0.125) + 1*(0.0625) = 0.3125
```

It's no different from binary integers, except we're just extending it to negative powers of 2 as we move right of the decimal point.

I hope that addresses at least part of your question.